# Word XML include picture 'manually' inserted into media folder

Tags: xml

**Background story:** I am writing a dxl (IBM Rational DOORS) script that exports contents of a module to xml, these xml sections go between the document tags.  The part that turns headings and text into xml text functions perfectly.  I have been tasked with adding an image exporter.  I have everything down *except* actually getting the image to show up properly.

I had my first encounter with xml last week on Wednesday, so I could do with some pointers and a hand troubleshooting.

**The problem:** I am at the stage where I have the script running and when I move the updated document.xml back into the word .zip file (and then change the extension back to .docx), I end up with a big ol white square telling me "This image cannot currently be displayed".

[image: it's times like these of minor annoyance and setback that I would like to pick an easier career.]

**The process:**

1. I change .docx to .zip and open up the zip folder.
2. Into the /word/media subfolder I insert the new images with names
   such as Image6.jpeg (given there were previously 5 images)
3. I update the xml in the section I want the pictures to occur, the
   following code:

   ```
           <w:p w:rsidR="00465B0A" w:rsidRDefault="00C35F8C">
             <w:r>
               <w:rPr>
                 <w:noProof/>
                 <w:lang w:eastAsia="en-AU"/>
               </w:rPr>
             <w:drawing>
               <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
               <wp:extent cx="5720080" cy="3221355"/>
               <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
               <wp:docPr id=picCount  name="Picture " picCount " descr="inserted picture"/>
                 <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                   <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
                 </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                 <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                   <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                     <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                       <pic:nvPicPr>
                         <pic:cNvPr id=picCount name="Picture " picCountU descr="inserted picture"/>
                           <pic:cNvPicPr>
                             <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1"/>
                           </pic:cNvPicPr>
                         </pic:nvPicPr>
                         <pic:blipFill>
                           <a:blip r:embed="rId"picCountU cstate="print"/>
                           <a:srcRect/>
                           <a:stretch>
                             <a:fillRect/>
                           </a:stretch>
                         </pic:blipFill>
                         <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
                           <a:xfrm>
                             <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                             <a:ext cx="5720080" cy="3221355"/>
                           </a:xfrm>
                           <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                             <a:avLst/>
                           </a:prstGeom>
                           <a:noFill/>
                           <a:ln>
                             <a:noFill/>
                             <a:miter lim="800000"/>
                             <a:headEnd/>
                             <a:tailEnd/>
                           </a:ln>
                         </pic:spPr>
                       </pic:pic>
                     </a:graphicData>
                   </a:graphic>
                 </wp:inline>
               </w:drawing>
             </w:r>
           </w:p>
   ```

picCountU and picCount are int variables I'm using to make sure the numbers assigned to these are not already present in the file.

4. I then zip up all the relevant elements, and rename the .zip to .docx

I'm at the stage now where I'm past the whole file being in such a poor state that it doesn't even open. But not much further.

I've checked the preamble before the body tag and it seems the same as the preamble from a test document I created that held an image.

--

I would very much appreciate any and all help given.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question haha, story of my life.

Unfamiliarity with the .docx structure was my downfall.

1. I needed a unique rId number (here, ##) on line

> ```
> <a:blip r:embed="rId##" cstate="print"/>
> ```

-> this means I will need to generate a separate number by reading the file word/_rels/document.xls.rels

2. To this document.xls.rels file, before  I need to add another line, something like:

> ```
> <Relationship Id="rId##" 
> Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image"
> Target="media/image5.jpeg"/>
> ```

Where image5.jpeg is the image that I have put into the word/media folder.  It is so, so very simple, and it works.  Now I just need to integrate the process into a couple of .dxl files.

Comment: Was it that simple? When I open a docx that I've added a photo to it contains all sorts of metadata wrapped around the :blip tag. Did you find that you needed any of the other metadata?